# On Inequality Concerning Deficient Numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisor-sum

By Definition a positive integer $N$ is d-deficient if $\sigma(N)=2N-d$.

Am I correct if I say that the inequality $N>d$ always hold for this definition?

Here is my attempt to show that it is true. First note that for any $N$, $\sigma(N)>N$.

If $N=d$ we have $\sigma(N)=N$ a contradiction.
If $d>N$ we have $\sigma(N)=2N-(N+k)$ for some positive integer k, and thus $\sigma(N)=-k$ a contradiction.

Am I correct Sir/Mam?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by $\sigma(N)$ you mean the sum of the divisors of $N$, then yes, if $N$ is $d$-deficient with

$$\sigma(N) = 2N - d,$$

then since $\sigma(N) \geq N$ (where equality holds if and only if $N = 1$), then you have

$$N \leq \sigma(N) = 2N - d \Longrightarrow d \leq N.$$

Again, equality holds if and only if $N = 1$.

Comment: $N\leq 2N - d \implies N + d \leq 2N \implies d \leq N$

Comment: My bad!  Mistake has been corrected.  Thanks @jameselmore!