# For what positive integer values $b,d$ does $(b^2-d)\mid(b^2-1)?$ hold?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, divisibility

I am curious about the answer to the following questions: And hope that you can help me

> For what positive integer values $b, d$ does
>   $$(b^2-d)|(b^2-1)?$$
>   hold?

Is it correct that the only solutions are those of the form $(b,1)$? The following leads to an affirmative answer:

The above expression implies $(b+\sqrt d)(b-\sqrt d)\mid(b^2-1)$. This means that either $b+\sqrt d$ or $b-\sqrt d$ divides $b^2-1$.

Using synthetic division in solving $\frac{b^2-1}{b+\sqrt d}$ and $\frac{b^2-1}{b-\sqrt d}$ I get both the remainer $d-1$. Since we want $d-1=0$ we have $d=1$. So the solution is $(b,d)=(b,1)$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We have too much freedom, if $b^2-1$ has many divisors, there are many $d$.

Comment: I've rewritten part of the question for clarity; please revert/revise any changes that don't reflect the intended meaning.

Comment: @Travis Thanks the question is more clear than before.

Comment: @JrAntalan You're welcome, I'm glad to help, and am glad I got it right.

Comment: @AndréNicolas thanks for your comment, I am so much interested in your comment, kindly elaborate more.

Comment: Pick a "random" $b$, like $b=5$. So we want to find the $d$ such that $25-d$ divides $24$. We can choose $d=1$, $d=13$, $d=17$, $d=19$, $d=21$, $d=22$, $d=23$, $d=24$, and if we allow negatives we can also pick $d=26$, and a few others.

Comment: I got it! Thanks a lot @AndréNicolas your a big help. I have the answer to my question now....

Comment: You are welcome. If there are additional conditions on $d$ that you have not mentioned, the solution might be unique. Note for instance that apart from $d=1$, all the other $d$ in the above example are "big," that is, bigger than $b^2/2$.

Comment: I will comment soonest Sir

Comment: I think that you should clarify the ring you are working in.

Comment: Its not a ring, Im working on Z+. Sir

Comment: This solution is not suitable?   $d=b^2-b\pm1$

Comment: Degradable to factor the number. $b\pm1=kq$ Then you can write:  $$d=b^2-k(b\mp1)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only a partial answer to your question.

Since we have the identity

$$\frac{b^2 - 1}{b^2 - d} = \frac{b^2 - d}{b^2 - d} + \frac{d - 1}{b^2 - d} = 1 + \frac{d - 1}{b^2 - d}$$

then your question is equivalent to

> > For what positive integer values $b, d$ does
> >     $$b^2 - d \mid d - 1$$
> >     hold?

Now, $b^2 - d \mid d - 1$ implies that $b^2 - d \leq d - 1$, which implies that $b^2 \leq 2d - 1$.

Unfortunately, this does not seem to narrow things that much.

Comment: Of course, by the AM-GM Inequality:

$$b \leq \frac{b^2 + 1}{2},$$

so that $b^2 \leq 2d - 1$ with $b,d$ positive implies that $b \leq d$.

Comment: With $b\leq d$ and with http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1121860/on-inequality-concerning-deficient-numbers......... Am I correct that a contradiction will arise Sir?

Comment: It seems that I am hoping so much, I forgot that I have $N=b^2$, so $b^2\geq d$ in my link. So there is no contradiction.

Comment: @JrAntalan, but *still*, you get the bounds $b \leq d \leq b^2$, where equality occurs if and only if $b = d = 1$.  Perhaps something else can be worked out from this.  It doesn't hurt to be hopeful, but it pays off to be prudent.

Comment: Yes sir, thanks a lot. Will try to work with that result..